# Link clicked RichTextBox

Tags: c#

How can I get the link that I have clicked and pass it to the `textBox`?

I know how to pass it to browser...

```
    private void Link_Clicked (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
private void Link_Clicked (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   myTextBox.Text = e.LinkText;
}
```

(Here, `myTextBox` is the name of the `RichTextBox` into which you want to insert the text.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not cast the sender to a (LinkButton)sender and then get the url text from there? If you know you are always using a LinkButton.